# Division width from picture inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the text to not be larger than the image, here is an example of the problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vsgi.png

And how I would like it to be

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tBRq.png

As you can see, when the picture is too tight, there is white borders, due to the text. I would like the text to not be larger than the picture.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="float:none;margin:0 auto;">
        <div class="polaroid center-block">
            <img src="./images/650x650.png" alt="Norway" class="img-responsive center-block" style="width:auto;height:auto">
            <div class="my_container" style="width:auto;height:auto">
                <p>The Troll's in Hardanger, Norway</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS :

```
body {
    margin: 25px;
}

div.polaroid {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

div.my_container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the image to 100%.

```
.polaroid img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

And the polaroid as well:

```
.polaroid {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but it stretched the picture, any idea to keep it as his original size ?

Comment: It is stretched because you set width and height, an image will auto resize if you only set one of them. Check you code if you set the height somewhere?

Comment: I checked and saw nothing, but :

.polaroid img{
    width: 100%;
}

Modify the width so it stretch no ?